# Display data from database into comboboxes

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have a website where I am trying to display data from the database stored in mysql into comboboxes. Basically it is a location database so I want to display an area and then based on the selection I want the next combobox to show the shops in that location. 
I am using php for this. I'm not too familiar with php. I've found loads of tutorials and examples but still I don't seem to be tweeking the code properly to get it to work. Also I'm not sure if I need a seperate php file with connection details or if I can put it all in the one file. I can't even populate one combobox at the minute so I am really trying to go back to basics.

Anyway this is the code so far (obviously I have html tags etc):

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="db.php"> 
<p>  
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option selected="selected">Select county</option> 
<p><input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search"> 
</form>
```

Then I have a db.php file where it stores my database details and sql query

```
<?php
resource mysql_connect ( [string server [, string username [, string password [, bool     new_link [, int client_flags]]]]])

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = ""; 
$pass = "";

bool mysql_select_db ( string database_name [, resource link_identifier])

$dbname = "databseLocations"; 
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$sql = "select * from locations where county=" . $_POST['county'] . " and name='" .     $_POST['county'] . "'"; 
echo $sql;

resource mysql_query ( string query [, resource link_identifier])

$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
echo "<p>",$row['id'],": ",$row['county']; 
}
?>
```

I need this data to be displayed on a map too based on selection but I can worry about that later.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Data is stored in database and not in phpmyadmin. Also I would suggest you to use `mysqli`. `mysql_*` are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming following query :

```
$sql = "select * from locations where county=" . $_POST['county'] . " and name='" .     $_POST['county'] . "'"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql);

echo '<select name="country" size="1">'
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['county'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

**Note : `mysql_*` are deprecated.**